# The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file

Tags: 20.04, updates

The command:

```
sudo apt update
```

doesn't work. The output of this command is the next image.

[image]

Comment: You've provided a picture of text, so I cannot check directly, but you copy & paste the URL in your picture into a browser, I'm betting you'll quickly discover it doesn't provide support for *focal* or 20.04.  PPA's are 3rd party sources, so all security & safety checks are your responsibility...

Comment: @guiverc Thanks I found a solution for it, I have removed the resource because the PPA has zero files in it.

Comment: Hi @TriumfMaqedonci. I have rolled back your latest revision since the older version seems to be more explanatory and searchable which can help future visitors as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That ppa has zero files in it. It's had zero files in it for a long time now. Unfortunately there's a lot of documentation pointing to that PPA online, so many people have it enabled with no benefit. The PPA itself even says it's discontinued. In short, remove that PPA.

[https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java](https://launchpad.net/%7Ewebupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java)

> [image]

Comment: Thanks, I have removed it, and now the update command is working. For removing I have used this command ```rm -f /etc/apt/source.list.d/webupd8team-ubuntu-java-focal.list```

Comment: I used `sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:webupd8team/java` to remove it

Comment: Man. Oracle really are hell bent on killing off Java as a viable technology. Its baffling that whilst doing this they attempt to take google to court blaming them for Javas decline. 

What a poisonous company.